# Table não ficando responsive bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4, table, layout-responsivo

Estou me aventurando no frontend apesa que gosto do backend. Estou com dificuldade de fazer a minha tabela responsivo. Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer um perfil de usuário,deixando ele no tamanho dos celular?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table class="table-sm rob" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <img src="{{ form1.avatar(180) }}" alt="" class="img-rounded img-sm" />
        </th>
        <th>
          <h4>{{ form1.first_name }} {{ form1.last_name }}</h4>
          <p>Sobre :{% if form1.about_me %}
            {{ form1.about_me }}
            {% endif %}</p>
           <p> {{ form1.email }}</p>
            Grau: {{ form1.grau }}
            {% if form1.last_seen %}
            Última visita: {{ form1.last_seen.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') }}</i>
            {% endif %}
          </p>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('edit_profile') }}" role="button"
              style="width: 130px; height: 50px">Edita Perfil</a>
            <a class="btn-sm btn-secondary"
              href="https://wordpress.com/log-in/pt-br?client_id=1854&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fpublic-api.wordpress.com%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D1854%26response_type%3Dcode%26blog_id%3D0%26state%3D39ad9d7e0e4eb19f951dce539ce091bd328c8d9660bcc1b2eaa182c8603b95ff%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fen.gravatar.com%252Fconnect%252F%253Faction%253Drequest_access_token"
              role="button" target="_blank" style="width: 130px; height: 50px">Trocar Avatar</a>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: Dalmo edita a pergunta e coloca ai o código da forma que é renderizado no browser. Isso `{{ form1.first_name }}`  não ajuda muito, coloca um HTML populado de forma que de para simular seu problema. E se vc está usando algum CSS além do CSS do Bootstrap tb inclui ai na pergunta, sem isso fica complicado te ajudar

Comment: Não entendi muito a sua pergunta mas é assim que ele é renderizado no navegado eu uso flask-python jinja2

Answer (score 2):

Falta a div em volta da tabela

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

percebo 2 questões claramente visíveis.

1. Na tela de perfil: (onde aparecem as informações do Piloto) os botões precisam ser em 
   outro formato, pois a dimensão deles é o que está expandindo essa tela. Te recomendo usar o botão "Trocar avatar" em cima da foto com uma posição absoluta, e o botão editar perfil pode ficar onde está mesmo, assim você reduz esse espaço horizontal excedido.
2. Na tela dos Voos (onde está listado Aeroporto de Aracaju) você pode utilizar uma estrutura mais simples, pois esse texto muito grande novamente está tomando um espaço horizontal. Mesmo que vc utilize um text wrap nele, essas informações serão muito grandes.

Agora já com as tabelas recomendo que use as tabelas do Semantic UI. Elas ficam totalmente na vertical sem scroll.

Answer (score 0):

voce pode resolver facilmente com essas class

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
<!-- table content here -->
</table>

<table class="table table-sm-responsive"><!-- ... --></table>
<table class="table table-md-responsive"><!-- ... --></table>
<table class="table table-lg-responsive"><!-- ... --></table>
<table class="table table-xl-responsive"><!-- ... --></table>
```

se tiver duvida de bootstrap voce pode consultar esse site

https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/